# Eclipse - Source --> "Override/Implement Methods" never works

Tags: java, xcode, eclipse, interface, overriding

When I try get the methods to be implemented while implementing a Interface or extending a Abstract Class I have tried using the Eclipse feature to auto generate the method skeletons for the To Override/Implement methods and it never worked for me but the compiler complains that methods need to be overridden.

I always get this message always I try to implement my Interfaces. If I implement any interface from the Java core Eclipse works fine.

[image]

Is it something I am doing wrong?  It is a immense helpful feature which I would like to leverage.

Details:

Eclipse Helios 3.6
Is it a bug in Eclipse?

Comment: It definitely works for me in Helios. Can you maybe show some sample code for which you are trying to generate skeleton code for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't turn on the "Build Automatically" option?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an inconsistency between Java 1.5 and Java 1.6 in your project setup? The handling of the @Override annotation changed which can sometimes mess things up.

Comment: Might be I will check on this.